# Is "Caveats to adhere" a valid English?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrases

Why I asked a question like that? Well, because I came across many contexts where "caveats" is close in meaning to "rules" instead of "risks" or "warnings".

The goal here is to tell someone that "you should follow the rules", "stick with the rules", etc...

Here's an example:

> IDK-L33T is a powerful device that can abstracts away many complex tasks; However, there are few rules to follow here.

If we replace the "rules to follow here." part with "caveats to adhere.", will the former sentence still valid?

In fact, is "caveats to adhere" itself valid?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us one context where the word was used to mean "rules"? To me, it is (mainly) used as a legal term. Why not just use "rules", "regulations" or even "principles"? Note that using "few" and "a few" could make a world of difference.

Comment: I would not employ *caveat* to mean rule. *Caveats* may be *observed*; *rules* may be *observed* or *followed* or *adhered to*, but bare *adhered* is ungrammatical.

Comment: Can you give some examples where it looks like *caveats* means *rules* rather than  *warnings* or *things to be wary of*? Is this in Indian English? Because I don't think it means that in American or British English.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase **caveats to adhere** is incorrect for two reasons.

[adhere](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/adhere) is intransitive (does not take an object) and on its own it simply means stick.. you have to use a preposition **to** if you wish to attach an object like rules or guidelines, for example **adhere to guidelines**.

[caveat](http://a%20warning%20to%20consider%20something%20before%20taking%20any%20more%20action) is not a rule but "a warning to consider something before taking any more action". The literal meaning (in latin) is "let a person be aware".

You cannot **adhere to** a caveat or warning- you can only **consider** it or **take it into account**.